# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'you can see diemension in the order, it was 3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

in one column in my df I have values and unite of measurements, so I extracted the values to another column however the `dtype` is still `object`

My table:

| cost | uom_value |
| --- | --- |
| 23226.8835 kg | 23226.8835 |
| 244.09 kg | 244.09 |
| 24226.5 kg | 24226.5 |
| 255.01 kg | 255.01 |

I wanted to convert them to `float` to use them in my calculations however I am getting the below error, even when doing a simple calculation such as `df['uom_value'].astype(float).sum()`
any help is appreciated

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df['uom_value'].astype(float).sum()

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5912, in NDFrame.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5905     results = [
   5906         self.iloc[:, i].astype(dtype, copy=copy)
   5907         for i in range(len(self.columns))
   5908     ]
   5910 else:
   5911     # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5912     new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5913     return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5915 # GH 33113: handle empty frame or series

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:419, in BaseBlockManager.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    418 def astype(self: T, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise") -> T:
--> 419     return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:304, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    302         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    303     else:
--> 304         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    305 except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    306     if not ignore_failures:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:580, in Block.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    562 """
    563 Coerce to the new dtype.
    564 
   (...)
    576 Block
    577 """
    578 values = self.values
--> 580 new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    582 new_values = maybe_coerce_values(new_values)
    583 newb = self.make_block(new_values)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:1292, in astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy, errors)
   1289     dtype = dtype.numpy_dtype
   1291 try:
-> 1292     new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1293 except (ValueError, TypeError):
   1294     # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings
   1295     #  trying to convert to float
   1296     if errors == "ignore":

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:1237, in astype_array(values, dtype, copy)
   1234     values = values.astype(dtype, copy=copy)
   1236 else:
-> 1237     values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1239 # in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object
   1240 if isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) and issubclass(values.dtype.type, str):

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:1181, in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1177     raise ValueError(msg)
   1179 if copy or is_object_dtype(arr.dtype) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
   1180     # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
-> 1181     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1183 return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'you can see diemension in the order, it was 3'
```

Comment: What float do you expect `you can see diemension in the order, it was 3` to evaluate to?

Comment: sorry didn't understand ur question?

Comment: Python is telling you that it can't convert `you can see diemension in the order, it was 3` to a float. What do you expect Python to do with that string? What float value do you want it to get? 3? If so you'll need to extract the numeric portion of the text somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use from pandas.to_numeric method. Note that it is better to set the coerce argument for your method based on your usage. For more detail, read about it in docs

Comment: I tried it before it didn't work, and coerce will provide NAN in case of an error, I know all rows are numbers so I don't want it to replace them with NAN

Comment: @Sam.H send your sample data for test

Comment: I used ur idea to flag those that are NAN then replace them manually. thanks for the tips

Comment: @Sam.H good luck